# Writing a program that creates a particular pattern using the number sign

Tags: python

How can this particular pattern be created using the number sign. **Note**, the first line must be indented.

***Write a program that creates a pattern like the one below. Let the user input
a nonnegative integer to determine the number of lines of the pattern.***

I am currently at this step, confused on how to indent the first line.

```
  for row in range(5):
        print('# #')

 # #
# #
# #
# #
# #
```

Comment: So show us your code.

Comment: Please (re-)read "[ask]", then [edit] your question to provide us a [mcve].  What have you tried so far?  What did it do?  Why did you think it would do something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Print the first line before the loop.

```
print " # #"
for row in range(4):
    print "# #"
```

Or use an `if` statement

```
for row in range(5):
    if row == 0:
        print " ", # trailing comma prints without a newline
    print "# "
```

Comment: Hm. Why not print just a single space first and then print the lines with a loop?